# DST Adjustments to Ola Hallengren's backup jobs not working as intended

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ola-hallengren

I have been using Ola Hallengren's backup/maintenance scripts for a few years but one thing that usually plagued me once a year was our backup location going near capacity after spring forward DST.

*I am aware that people will advise an obvious way to avoid this is to set SQL Server to use UTC but that is not possible in my case.*

As this only happens once a year, the only concern is a little extra space is being used on the backup drives. As the backup schedule is nightly full backups with 5 days (120h) retention, this means that an extra days worth of backups are kept as their ages are an hour shorter when calculated.

This all comes out in the wash after 5 days when the math returns to normal but I wanted to be proactive this year and give future Matt a break.

So, I changed my `@CleanupTime` to 119 from 120 thinking that should fix it and be a safe value to leave year round since the FULL job runs nightly.

I did just that but this morning when I looked I still have 6 days of full backups. I looked at the commandlog and saw that it did acknowledge my 119 change. The datetime used was 2024-03-09T02:03:45 and the execution time was 2024-03-14 01:03:45.637

```
DECLARE @ReturnCode int EXECUTE @ReturnCode = [master].dbo.xp_delete_file 0, N'\\prd-kan-bk02\mssql\PRD-KAN-SQL04\5T\FULL', 'bak', '2024-03-09T02:03:45' IF @ReturnCode <> 0 RAISERROR('Error deleting files.', 16, 1)
```

However I still have full backups in my directory that are 1 hour older than that. Again, this will not be an issue in a couple of days. I am missing something in either how the scripts or SQL SERVER is doing date math perhaps.

Is there a cleanuptime I can use that still gives me 5d of full backups while being cognizant of DST time changes?

Comment: In hindsight I think using 119 wont work long term as it will drop the 5th day backup... however I still have 6 days worth anyway so I am missing something.